# How to consume HttpClient from F#?

Tags: f#, task-parallel-library, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, c#-to-f#

I'm new to F# and stuck in understanding async in F# from the perspective of a C# developer. Say having the following snippet in C#:

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

How to write the same in F#?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a function that should do what you're looking for (note that you'll have to wrap the code in an asynchronous computation expression in order to use the let! syntax):

```
let getAsync (url:string) = 
    async {
        let httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
        let! response = httpClient.GetAsync(url) |> Async.AwaitTask
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () |> ignore
        let! content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        return content
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't the first two `let`s be `use`s instead? (httpClient & response being IDisposable)

Comment: Probably no, `HttpClient` is [special in that](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Answer (score 8):

You'll want to at least read and be aware of the established patterns in [Http.fs](https://github.com/haf/Http.fs) if you're doing anything with `HttpClient` in F#.

[See comments] TL;DR ... [but Beware the Share](https://books.google.ie/books?id=sS7aPtrUuw4C&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=beware+the+share+udi+dahan&source=bl&ots=-ic0ST3euM&sig=BMZpQjZ-94jQS7W9laOrvxiqpBo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3maaAxPLcAhVrBcAKHd6aCGAQ6AEwCXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=beware%20the%20share%20udi%20dahan&f=false). As noted by @pimbrouwers, it should be noted that you don't necessarily *have* to then use it though - subsetting and/or evolving your own set of helpers in your context can lead you to a better fitting abstraction (and bring you the benefits of the learning on the way).

To this point: It's considered idiomatic practice in F# to keep rarely used and/or overly specific helpers in a non-central location.

Comment: No disrespect intended. But I find answers referring someone directly to a library to be such a cop out. Sure, inevitably you may end up using it. But from my perspective you should always journey there yourself first. Otherwise we'll end up with a bunch of programmers who've become so removed from what they're actually trying to do, that they can only accomplish their jobs using external library's. A perfect example of this is ADO.NET. You would be SHOCKED how many .NET developers I've made that wouldn't know the first thing about brokering a `SqlConnection` and executing a `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Point being, try it yourself first. Make mistakes. Screw it up royally (I know I always do). But actually LEARN something in the process.

Comment: I somewhat agree; I would not write the same answer today. However my point about not writing F# wrapping for `HttpClient` without being aware of a library in widespread use remains - for example sticking with the same naming for the same concepts etc. Will edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `async`:

```
let readString (url: Uri) = async {
    let httpClient = new HttpClient();
    let! response = httpClient.GetAsync(url) |> Async.AwaitTask
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() |> ignore
    return! response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents. But my understanding is that we should be handling the `HttpRequestException` when using `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`.

Below is the start of  a module wrapping `HttpClient` that will buffer the response of a URL into a `string` and safely wrap in a `Result<'a, 'b>` for improved fault tolerance.

```
module Http =
    open System    
    open System.Net.Http

    let getStringAsync url =
        async {
            let httpClient = new HttpClient() 
            // This can be easily be made into a HttpClientFactory.Create() call
            // if you're using >= netcore2.1

            try 
                use! resp = httpClient.GetAsync(Uri(url), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead) |> Async.AwaitTask                       
                resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode |> ignore

                let! str = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                return Ok str
            with
            | :? HttpRequestException as ex -> return ex.Message |> Error
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `FSharp.Control.FusionTasks` and you will have clear syntax without `|> Async.AwaitTask` like

```
   let httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient ()

   let getAsync (url:string) = 
    async {
        let! response = httpClient.GetAsync url
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () |> ignore
        let! content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ()
        return content
    }
```